# Tata photon 3g dongle crashes after upgrading my OS to Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash

I have upgraded my macbook's OS to yosemite(MacOSX 10.10). Since then whenever I connect my dongle(Tata Photon 3G), it crashes with a crash report.

I came across few patch files for same device having issues with Mavericks.
Is there any patch file or something I can do to make it work fine on yosemite other than downgrading it back to mavericks?

I am able to use internet when I am using my cell as wifi hotspot.

Comment: Any luck so far? Even I am facing the issue.

Comment: Not yet.It seems either I need to visit Tata photon's customer care or have to wait for Yosemite's next update in case I want to continue with Yosemite. I will update my question if I get any progress in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to make dongle work in the yosemite(Mac OS 10.10).

Go to the system preference and click on network.

In network it will show you the dongle option like in my case my dongle name is ZTEUSBModem.

And enter the phone number "*99#". Click on connect.

Your mac is ready to work with the dongle. There will be no need to run the tata docomo app.

Its working in 3g mode.

Its working good for my mac.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me : http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1758075

Comment: This package seems only for Huawei. My device is ZTE MF190. I already went through this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605462) . It seems they still don't have anything for ZTE. I tried this package also. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah ok !! I assumed yours being a Huwaei.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Huawei MODEM.  I went to System Preferences -> Network -> Chose the Huawei MODEM on the left pane.

For telephone number I used #777, username internet and password internet and then connected.  It is working OK

It also may be an issue with installation of flash.  Since the last time when it was not working I have also installed / upgraded flash on the mac